# $or-Operator in MongoDB (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Hey guys I'd like to search for documents by the **$or**-Operator...
At first I'm inserting 3 documents:

```
$aDocument = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'WinZIP',
    'shorttext' => 'ZIP / UNZIP Programm' );

$oCollection->insert( $aDocument );

$aDocument = array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'WinRar',
    'shorttext' => 'ZIP / UNZIP Programm mit RAR-Unterstützung' );

$oCollection->insert( $aDocument );

$aDocument = array(
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => '7zip',
    'shorttext' => 'ZIP / UNZIP Programm mit RAR- und 7z-Unterstützung' );

$oCollection->insert( $aDocument );
```

Then I'm creating a regex for my query:

```
$oSearchRegex = new MongoRegex( "/zip/i" );
```

Now I'd like to search for the string 'zip' in 'name' or 'shorttext'... It should be like this:

```
$oCursor = $oCollection->find( array( '$or' => array( array( 'name' => $oSearchRegex ), array( 'shorttext' => $oSearchRegex ) ) ) );
```

But this doesn't work... When I just search in one index, it works really fine.. Example:

```
$oCursor = $oCollection->find( array( 'name' => $oSearchRegex ) );
```

Any solutions?

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using ? your syntax seems perfect

Comment: I don't know if that's the version but when I type 'mongo' in on my server the following output appears: MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4.

Comment: the "or" operator was included only from version 1.7.x onwards

Comment: Okay... Then I've to try updating mongodb :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have `1.4.4 MongoDB` version but `"or" operator was included only from version 1.7.x` onwards

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! Worked fine. I'm now running version 2.2.0 and the results are fine! :)